# Customize the default error on vuetify's v-data-table : "no matching records found"

Tags: vuetify.js

How can I change the warning message "no matching records found" by a customized one?
For example:
[I want to change this by my own customisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caHZd.png)

Shown in the documentation : [Vutify documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#search)

We have the message: "No matching records found" displayed and I want to change it by my own v-alert.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use slots to change content. The relevant [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots-no-results).

solution:

```
<template v-slot:no-results>
    <span>Not Found Data</span>
</template>
```